# Strange escape character added to record's message in Python logger

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, logging, escaping

I am facing a weird issue.

The following code

```
logger.info("Setting coordinates to [lat: " + str(self.curr_coord.latitude())
                + ", lng: " + str(self.curr_coord.longitude())
                + "]")
```

The values returned by the functions mentioned above are simple `double`.

produces a string, which contains escape character after `str(self.curr_coord.latitude())`. In my custom logging handler I am connecting to a SQLite3 database file. In addition I have the ability to dump the log records into a CSV file.

The code above produces an entry that is exported the following entry

```
2021-10-26T14:47:39.528605+02:00,0,geointelkit,"Setting coordinates to [lat: 48.9475, lng: 8.4106]"
```

My CSV writer looks like this:

```
with open(db_dump_filename, "w", newline="") as csv_dump_file:
    cols = ["Timestamp", "Level", "Source", "Message"]
    db_exporter = csv.writer(csv_dump_file)
    db_exporter.writerow(cols)
    db_exporter.writerows(entries)
```

All of my other entries do not have quotation marks. At first I thought it may be the length of the message and some weird stuff SQLite is doing with it. However after adding an even longer string I didn't get the same problem.

The next thing I did was to customize the CSV writer:

```
with open(db_dump_filename, "w", newline="") as csv_dump_file:
    cols = ["Timestamp", "Level", "Source", "Message"]
    db_exporter = csv.writer(csv_dump_file,
                             quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                             delimiter=",",
                             escapechar="#")
    db_exporter.writerow(cols)
    db_exporter.writerows(entries)
```

The modified writer's output for that entry was

```
2021-10-26T14:47:39.528605+02:00,0,geointelkit,Setting coordinates to [lat: 48.9475#, lng: 8.4106]
```

Notice the `#` after `48.9475`. While I do some formatting in my custom handler in regards to the records it handles it is only related to the timestamp (first column) and value after it (second column), which is simply mapping the logger level numeric values (20, 30, 40...) to the ones I use in my application. The record message is not touched in any way. Here is the formatter I'm using in my custom logger class:

```
self.formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelno)d %(name)s %(message)s",
                                   datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

The custom handler and custom logger are shown below. `LogLevel` is a simple class that includes (beside my different levels of logging) functions for mapping a log level to different representation. I didn't include it since it's not important.

```
LogEntry = namedtuple("LogEntry", "dtime lvl src msg")

class LogHandlerSQLite(logging.Handler):
    db_init_script = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs(
            TimeStamp   TEXT,
            Level       INT,
            Source      TEXT,
            Message     TEXT
        );
        """

    db_clear_script = """
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logs;
    """

    db_insert_script = """
        INSERT INTO logs(
            Timestamp,
            Level,
            Source,
            Message
        )
        VALUES (
            '%(tstamp)s',
            %(levelno)d,
            '%(name)s',
            '%(message)s'
       );
       """

    db_get_all = """
        SELECT *
        FROM logs
    """

    def __init__(self, db_path="logs.db"):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.db = db_path
        conn = sq3.connect(self.db)
        conn.execute(LogHandlerSQLite.db_init_script)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def dump(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger("geointelkit")
        logger.info("Dumping log records to CSV file")

        conn = sq3.connect(self.db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(self.db_get_all)
        entries = cur.fetchall()
        conn.close()

        db_dump_filename = self.rename_db_file(add_extension=False) + ".csv"
        with open(db_dump_filename, "w", newline="") as csv_dump_file:
            cols = ["Timestamp", "Level", "Source", "Message"]
            db_exporter = csv.writer(csv_dump_file,
                                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                                     delimiter=",",
                                     escapechar="#")
            db_exporter.writerow(cols)
            db_exporter.writerows(entries)

    def clear_entries(self):
        conn = sq3.connect(self.db)
        # Drop current logs table
        conn.execute(LogHandlerSQLite.db_clear_script)
        # Shrink size of DB on the filesystem as much as possible
        conn.execute("VACUUM")
        # Create an empty one
        conn.execute(LogHandlerSQLite.db_init_script)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def format_time(self, record):
        # FIXME Timestamp includes microseconds
        record.tstamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created, datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat()

    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emits a log entry after processing it. The processing includes

         * formatting the entry's structure
         * formatting the datetime component
         * adding exception information (in case the log entry was emitted due to exception)
         * mapping of the log level (Python) to custom level that allows it to be used in the model and log console

        In addition the entry is inserted into a database, which can then be viewed by and processed with external tools

        Args:
            record: Log entry

        Returns:

        """
        # Format log entry
        self.format(record)
        self.format_time(record)
        if record.exc_info:  # for exceptions
            record.exc_text = logging._defaultFormatter.formatException(record.exc_info)
        else:
            record.exc_text = ""

        # Map Python logging module's levels to the custom ones
        if record.levelno == 10:
            record.levelno = LogEntriesModel.LoggingLevel.DEBUG # 3
        elif record.levelno == 20:
            record.levelno = LogEntriesModel.LoggingLevel.INFO  # 0
        elif record.levelno == 30:
            record.levelno = LogEntriesModel.LoggingLevel.WARN  # 1
        elif record.levelno == 40:
            record.levelno = LogEntriesModel.LoggingLevel.ERROR # 2

        # Insert the log record
        sql = LogHandlerSQLite.db_insert_script % record.__dict__
        conn = sq3.connect(self.db)
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def rename_db_file(self, add_extension=False):
        db_old_name = os.path.splitext(self.db)[0]
        db_new_name = db_old_name + "_" \
                      + datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat().replace(":", "-").replace(" ", "_")

        if add_extension:
            db_new_name = db_new_name + os.path.splitext(self.db)[1]

        return db_new_name

    def close(self):
        """
        Clean-up procedure called during shutdown of the logger that uses the handler
        The previously created log database is renamed by adding the current system
        time stamp. This is done to ensure that the database can be viewed later (e.g.
        bug report) and not overwritten when the logging is setup again

        Returns:

        """
        db_new_name = self.rename_db_file(add_extension=True)
        os.rename(self.db, db_new_name)
        super().close()


class SQLiteLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name="geointelkit", level=logging.DEBUG, db_path="logs.db"):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, level)

        self.formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelno)d %(name)s %(message)s",
                                           datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        self.handler = LogHandlerSQLite(db_path=db_path)
        self.handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.addHandler(self.handler)

    def clear_entries(self):
        self.handler.clear_entries()

    def dump(self):
        self.handler.dump()


def setup_logger():
    logging.setLoggerClass(SQLiteLogger)
```

Last but not least changing the `escapechar` to a blank space `" "` resulted in double blank spaces in ALL messages even those that are just a simple short string. Here are some examples including the problematic log record from above:

```
2021-10-26T15:12:09.467067+02:00,3,geointelkit,Adding  OpenStreetMaps  view
2021-10-26T15:12:09.536681+02:00,0,geointelkit,Setting  coordinates  to  [lat:  48.9475 ,  lng:  8.4106]
```

Comment: What exactly does `self.curr_coord.latitude()` return and is it possible to get a `repr` of that…?

Comment: What do you expect? It's a CSV file and you specify `,` as the delimiter *and* want strings to be unquoted *and* those strings contain commas themselves, so these **need** to be escaped via `escapechar`. So either you quote these strings `""` *or* use an escape char *or* CSV is not the right format for your application.

Comment: @deceze The function is coming from `QGeoCoordinate` and returns a double. I will add the information to my question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @a_guest Can you post this as the answer. I thought that the delimiter is something that is added and not that the writer analyzes the strings it gets and extracts delimiter from those. With your suggestion I fixed the issue namely by changing the delimiter to be different than a comma.

Comment: @rbaleksandar You could add an answer yourself, describing how you solved the problem with the relevant code. The purpose of the CSV writer is to produce a valid CSV file and for that it needs to deal with strings that contain the delimiter char. The default way is to quote strings which is probably very intuitive. Strings are quoted in many formats e.g. JSON or Python itself. If you change the delimiter, you need to make sure to use the same delimiter for parsing the file. Typically `.csv` files use a comma as the separator, as this is what the format name promises ("comma-separated values").

Comment: Also, using `escapechar` together with `QUOTE_NONE` doesn't make much sense, since `escapechar` is meant to escape quotes inside quoted fields (the default is another quote, or a `\` (Unix style)).